# displaying limited data at each page when gone to next page

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I would not write the code. I want just hint or a sample example.
How to get 5 records at each page when going to next page or reload the same page. This is a phone gap app with html & using sqlite. How could I do it using jquery or JavaScript. Any answer is most welcome. Can we do this without using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you should use jQuery datatable. Its robust and much faster, here is an example:
https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: I got best solution  but I would like expect to do it without plugin.

Comment: yeah! most of the people do not want to use third party tools,  that's why i was recommended you to use DataTable.